# What is the time complexity for this code?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int i=1,n;
   cin>>n;
   for(i;i<=n;i=i*2)
      printf("hey");
   return 0;
}
```

I'm confused whether the time complexity for the above code is O(log n) or O( sqrt n).
I think it's O(sqrt n) as no of iterations is 3 for n=5 and sqrt(5)~3 but some answers show it as O(logn). Please Explain...

Comment: What do *you* think? Why do you think that? If we know how you think then it's easier for us to point out mistakes (if there are any), or confirm your thoughts.

Comment: Dude you are iterating the loop, so it is O(n/2) or generally O(N) only.

Comment: Im sorry.. I have edited it please take a look at it once  more.

Comment: The `int i = n;` line *before* `n` has a value is meaningless at best and causes UB at worst. Move that to after the `cin >> n;` and the loop will be either O(1) (if n > 0) or will run forever (if n <= 0).

Answer (score 2):

Let's forget about the `5` and assume it goes to a sufficiently large number just for the sake of algorithm.

The facts are:

1. You start at 1
2. At each iteration you double (2x) the index

Therefore we can say that `n = 2^nit` where `nit` is the number of iterations and `n` is the "size" of your problem whatever it represents.

It follows that `log(n) = nit * log(2)`. Then `nit = log(n)/log(2)`.

So the conclusion is `nit ~ O(log(n))`